# Error inside docker container: Could not download spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.5.4.jar (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.5.4)

Tags: spring, docker, gradle, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a spring batch application configured with docker-compose.yml. To run the project there is a run.sh file and it spinup several containers. DB container gets up and running without issues. But the container which runs the spring application fails with the below error.

```
 Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.5.4.jar (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.5.4)
      > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.5.4/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.5.4.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.5.4/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.5.4.jar'.
            > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not download sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.3.jar (org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/3.3/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.3.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/3.3/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.3.jar'.
```

`
But I can download those jar files from my local machine. So jars are residing in those locations. I think this container can't access the internet to download these files. There's no way to use a terminal inside the container to execute a ping command since it is exiting right after giving this error. (But I pinged google.com in DB container and it worked.So this problem is only for that particular container)

There was a workaround to add this `rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts'` in settings.gradle. But then it says `Task 'bootRun' not found in root project '*'`. So I think no use in this workaround and what I want to solve is the network connection issue of the container.

Comment: Simple way is build spring boot to jar on Host not on docker build or container. Then spring boot application dockerfile just copy spring boot application jar from host.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change any script or docker-compose file.

Comment: Do you ever use gradle build your spring boot app jar successfully on your host ?

Comment: spring boot application Dockerfile ?

Comment: Run docker compose in your machine or remote server ? OS ? docker version ?

Comment: build.gradle.kts ?

Comment: runing docker-compose in local machine

Comment: my suspicion is that the base image in your docker file has some issues with SSL handshake. Is the base image maybe custom or particularly old? If so, try to change the base image to "ubuntu" - and see if the error persists.

Comment: But this same code works for another without any changes @Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with this part of the error msg: `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

To fix, you have to download the certificate of https://plugins.gradle.org/ and add that to cacerts file of the jdk (refer this [link](https://apisero.com/how-to-resolve-pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-issue/) to see how to install the certificate)

Since I had this problem inside a container I manually replaced the cacerts file inside the container with the local cacerts file (which already contains the certificate of gradle.org).

So this whole problem is with the jdk image which was used to create the container.